# How to add Image in MoreViewController of Tabbar Controller?

Tags: objective-c, imageview, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbaritem

I have more than 6 ViewController in Tabbar controller so it will display 2 tab in moreViewcontroller Tableview
Now i dont know how to add image item and title for this 2 tab??

***Below is code of My tabbar implemetation***

```
NSArray *arrayVC=[[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:objNewsFeedNavi,objReqNavi,objMsgNavi,objNotificationNavi,objProfileNavi,objChatNavi, nil];

[self.objTb setViewControllers:arrayVC];
UITabBarItem *itemNewsFeed=[self.objTb.tabBar.items objectAtIndex:0];
itemNewsFeed.title=@"News Feed";

itemNewsFeed.image = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"Newsfeed.png"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];

UITabBarItem *itemReq=[self.objTb.tabBar.items objectAtIndex:1];
itemReq.title=@"Request";
itemReq.image = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"request.jpg"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];

UITabBarItem *itemMsg=[self.objTb.tabBar.items objectAtIndex:2];
itemMsg.title=@"Messenger";
itemMsg.image = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"messenger.png"]    imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];

UITabBarItem *itemNotification=[self.objTb.tabBar.items   objectAtIndex:3];

itemNotification.title=@"Notification";

itemNotification.image = [[UIImage  imageNamed:@"notificationBlue.png"]  imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];

UITabBarItem *itemProfile=[self.objTb.tabBar.items objectAtIndex:4];
itemProfile.title=@"Profile"; 
itemNotification.image = [[UIImage  imageNamed:@"profile.png"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];
```